# Solr returning weird scores

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to set up Solr for my data, I have configured all the things and the search seems to be working fine but sometimes I am getting weird results.

For example, if I am searching for a term `vicryl ctx 2-0 70` in the results, I have

> 1. VICRYL VIOLETT GEFL | 2-0 | 1 x CTX PLUS | 1 x 70 | - | 36
> 2. VICRYL PLUS VIOLETT GEFL | 2-0 | 1 x CTX PLUS | 1 x 70 | - | 36
> 3. SPONGOSTAN* Film Gelatinehämostyptikum, 200 x 70 x 0,5 mm
> 4. SPONGOSTAN* Standard Gelatinehämostyptikum, 70 x 50 x 10 mm
> 5. SPONOGSTAN* Spezial Gelatinehämostyptikum, 70 x 50 x 1 mm
> 6. VICRYL VIOL GEFL VIOLETT GEFL | 2-0 | 1 x SH1 PLUS | 1 x 70 | - | 12

I don't understand why I am getting results no.4 and no.5 before no.6. I looked at analysis and I found nothing wrong with that...

Below is my schema.xml:

```xml
<fieldtype class="solr.TextField" name="text_exact_matches" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>        
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>

<fieldtype class="solr.TextField" name="text_related_matches" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the "explain" output of the results, with [Solr's debugging parameters](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Debugging).  That will give you detailed explanations of how the score was arrived at.

Comment: also use http://explain.solr.pl/ to visualize the explanation - great tool.